Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match method: PUT, URL: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1", found none
I am trying to create unit tests for a full-stack application I am writing to practice learning angular. I am trying to create mock requests to test the functions of my frontend without actually making requests to the backend. This test keeps saying that it is not receving a put request, although the function that sends the put request is being entered. The put request is being sent when the angular server is live, just not when the test is being ran.
The test
it('Testing OnSubmit with valid input', async () => {
    const httpTesting = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    const expectedUser = {id: 1, name: 'Test', Bankroll: 500, hours: 100, winrate: 5};
    //const alertSpy = spyOn(window, 'alert');
    const expectedSessions = [
      { id: 1, user_id: 1, buyIn: 300, cashOut: 400, timePlayed: 3 },
      { id: 2, user_id: 1, buyIn: 100, cashOut: 400, timePlayed: 3 },
      { id: 3, user_id: 1, buyIn: 200, cashOut: 400, timePlayed: 3 }
    ];

    component.newSession = {user_id: 1, buyIn: 100, cashOut: 200, timePlayed: 5};

    
    component.onSubmit();
    await fixture.whenStable();

    const submitReq = httpTesting.expectOne({ method: 'POST', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions' }).flush({}); 

    const updateReq = httpTesting.expectOne({method: 'PUT', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1'}).flush(''); 
    
    const getReq = httpTesting.expectOne({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1' }).flush(expectedUser); 

    const sessionsByReq = httpTesting.expectOne({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions' }).flush(expectedSessions); 


    
    //expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
   /* expect(component.newSession).toEqual({
      user_id: 1,
      buyIn: 0,
      cashOut: 0,
      timePlayed: 0
    });*/
    //expect(component.user1).toEqual(expectedUser);
    //expect(component.updatedSessions).toEqual(expectedSessions);
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
      
  })

The function being tested
async onSubmit(): Promise<void> {
    const userID = 1;
    if(this.newSession.buyIn > 0 && this.newSession.cashOut >= 0 && this.newSession.timePlayed > 0) {
      await this.dashService.submitSession(this.newSession);
      console.log('sent post')
    } else {
      alert("Invalid input");
    } 
    await this.dashService.updateUser();
    this.user1 = await this.dashService.getUser(userID);
    this.updatedSessions =  (await this.dashService.sessionsByUser()).sort((a: session, b: session ) => a.id - b.id);
    this.newSession = {
      user_id: 1,
      buyIn: 0,
      cashOut: 0,
      timePlayed: 0
    }
  }

The function to make the put request.
 async updateUser(): Promise<any> {
        console.log('PUT REQ ENTERED')
        return await lastValueFrom(this.http.put(`${this.urlPut}/1`, ''));
    }

The error
    LOG: '+++++++++++++++++++'
Chrome 125.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 6 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
LOG: '==============='                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Chrome 125.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 6 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 125.0.0.0 (Windows 10) DashComponent Testing OnSubmit with valid input FAILED                                                                                                                                             
        Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match method: PUT, URL: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1", found none. Requests received are: GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/sessions, GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/1.
            at HttpClientTestingBackend.expectOne (node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/http/testing.mjs:270:19)
            at UserContext.<anonymous> (src/app/dash/dash.component.spec.ts:86:35)
            at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
            at asyncGeneratorStep (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:3:1)
            at apply (node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/asyncToGenerator.js:22:1)
            at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:365:28)
            at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-testing.js:2070:39)
            at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:364:34)
            at ZoneImpl.run (node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:111:43)
            at node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone.js:2447:40
LOG: 'sent post'                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Chrome 125.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.06 secs)
LOG: 'PUT REQ ENTERED'                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Chrome 125.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.06 secs)
LOG: '+++++++++++++++++++'                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Chrome 125.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 1 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.06 secs)
LOG: '+++++++++++++++++++'
Chrome 125.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 2 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.069 secs)
LOG: '+++++++++++++++++++'                                                                                                                                                                                                       
Chrome 125.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 2 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.069 secs)
Chrome 125.0.0.0 (Windows 10): Executed 6 of 6 (1 FAILED) (0.106 secs / 0.085 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 5 SUCCESS

